# 2d Physics engine for bridge constructor game

Tags: android, ios, mobile, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm looking for a 2d physics engine for mobile platforms (iOS, Android), which will allow me to create a bridge constructor game.

Please point me in the right direction.

Edit:

I think the engine should support tension (bridge parts may "break" depending on forces which apply to them). Also joints may "break" as well. So my question is there an engine, which provides these, or do I have to write this logic by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can get the reaction force and torque off the joint. You can query these forces after each time step and destroy the joint when your threshold is exceeded." - Quote from Erin Catto, the creator of **box2d**!

http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1079

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need - a confirmation, that this task is possible with box2D.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what programming language you are building your game... but I would recommend Box2D. You can find it ported to most languages.

Comment: I also thought about Box2D, however I'm not sure if it supports tension (bridge parts may "break" depending on forces which apply to them). Also joints may "break" as well. So my question are these features provided with engine or do I have to implement them by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/documentation.php), which has [free versions](http://chipmunk-physics.net/chipmunkPro.php) and paid versions with more stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure if it supports tension (bridge parts may "break" depending on forces which apply to them). Also joints may "break" as well. So my question are these features provided with engine or do I have to implement them by myself?

Comment: If that's a requirement you should state it explicitly in your question.